# Nested for loop issue TCL

Tags: loops, for-loop, nested, tcl

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is a trial program

puts "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
set y "0.0.0.0"

set z [split $y "."]
puts "z=$z"
lreplace $z 0 5
puts "z $z"
set v [llength $z]
puts "length of array=  $v"
puts "in the loop-------->\n"
puts " "
incr v -1
puts $v
for {set ml $v } { $ml >= 0} { puts "$ml =ml"} {
    for { set nl [lindex $z $ml]} { $nl >=4} { puts "$nl=nl"} {
        puts $nl
        after 2000
        lset z  $ml $nl
        incr $nl
    }
    after 2000
    incr ml -1
}
```

I am not able to enter the second for loop, is this a formatting issue ?
gives me some weird error. I added the sleep just to check whats happening so ignore that.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `lreplace $z 0 5`?

Comment: +1 Jerry's comment: `lreplace $z 0 5` doesn't actually do anything in this program.  The command creates a result list based on the elements in z with all those elements up to (non-existent) index 5 deleted, and then you don't assign this result list anywhere.

Comment: If your intention was to replace the 0:s with 5:s, this will work better: `set z [lmap elem $z { expr { $elem == 0 ? 5 : $elem } }]`

Comment: should be `incr nl` not `incr $nl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code your inner loop is only evaluating if `nl >=4`.
nl will be initialized as 0 from `[lindex $z $ml]`

Since you are incrementing $nl, my guess is you should change this line:

```
for { set nl [lindex $z $ml]} { $nl >=4} { puts "$nl=nl"} {
```

to this instead:

```
for { set nl [lindex $z $ml]} { $nl <=4} { puts "$nl=nl"} {
```

Comment: Thanks Niall. I tried that and nl never increments. 0=nl
0=nl
0=nl
0=nl
^C

Comment: In fact the 0th element in z is also not getting replaced :(

Comment: z=0 0 0 0
z 0 0 0 0
length of array=  4
in the loop-------->

Comment: Your incr statement seems a bit odd `$nl` is a value, you may need to use `incr nl`

Comment: Absolutely right ! Just figured it out. Thank you very much for your inputs

Answer (score 2):

Was it perchance something like this you intended?

```
# This is a trial program

puts "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
set y "0.0.0.0"

set z [split $y "."]
puts "\$z=$z"
set v [llength $z]
# the term 'array' means associative array in Tcl, better use 'list'
puts "length of list=  $v"
puts "in the loop-------->\n\n"
incr v -1
puts "\$v=$v"
for {set ml $v} {$ml >= 0} {incr ml -1} {
    for {set nl [lindex $z $ml]} {$nl <= 4} {incr nl} {
        lset z $ml $nl
        puts $z
    }
}
```

Note that I've moved the `incr` command invocations to the third argument (the *next* command string, as the documentation puts it) of the `for` command invocations.  You can put anything you want to run at the end of each iteration there, including `puts` commands as you did, but it's a convention and good practice to have the loop-control-changing commands (whatever they may be) there, and not much else.

Comment: You'll want to change your `#!` line.

Comment: Yes, well, I just copied it from the OP's code.  I figured if it worked for him I'd just leave it in.  But now I think I'll remove it to avoid confusion. Thank you for pointing it out.